# How to receive a datastream from a device on your computer, in C#

Tags: c#, wav, audio-recording

I plan to build a small audio-recorder app in C#.
My laptop has a built in Microphone that's always active, so I want to use that as an early-stage test. I would simply start recording, save the file as a .wav or even use the LAME dll to make it into an MP3.

The problem is, I don't know how to contact that microphone. Do I use a library that can detect a device, or do I just catch a stream of bytes from the port that the device is on?

I don't have any experience with receiving data from connected devices. I suppose that I'll need to enter all the data into a byte array and then Serialize that into a WAV file, but I'm not sure.

Can I get some pointers on this subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/).

Comment: I shall look into it. The introduction seems promissing.